# AWS CloudWatch unused custom metrics retention and pricing - 2018

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

It looks like custom metrics will be kept for 15 months, if I understand it correctly, since they get aggregated to higher resolution, according to https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/faqs. Does it mean we have to pay for at least 15 months once we create a custom metric?

I have CloudWatch agent installed to collect various metrics using user_data. It creates new metrics for every new instances. After running many tests, I have more than 6,000 custom metrics, but most of them are unused. Since there is no way to delete custom metrics, do I get charged for those unused metrics until they expire (15 months)? I hope I'm wrong on this :]

Please clarify how we get charged for unused custom metrics.

Answer (score 3):

You will not get charged for those. You will get charged for the metric for the duration you publish data onto them. It's not very clear on the [CloudWatch pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/) but they hint it in the [original pricing reduction blogpost](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-price-reduction-cloudwatch-custom-metrics/).

You will get charged though on the retrieval of those (API costs).

Comment: This was confirmed to me by AWS Support today. The [pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/) states that "All custom metrics charges are prorated by the hour and metered only when you send metrics to CloudWatch". By this, they mean that they charge 1/720 of the monthly costs for the custom metrics for every hour in which you push at least one data point to the custom metric (counting 30 * 24 = 720 hours in a month).

Answer (score 0):

we have the same issue to resolve. waiting for clearification from aws

Comment: Hello! Did you get an answer from AWS?