# How much do you end up paying for each metric created by Container Insights for EKS for short lived pods?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I just enabled Container Insights in my EKS cluster following the Amazon's [Quick Start Setup for Conainer Insights on Amazon EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-setup-EKS-quickstart.html).

I see that the number of metrics is quickly increasing, CloudWatch > Metrics > Custom Namespaces > ContainerInsights is already 1279 metrics with the majority of them under ClusterName, Namespace, Podname (979 metrics)

Under ContainerInsights > ClusterName, Namespace, PodName is creating 4-5 metrics for each new pod and the number of pods steadily increase since we have Airflow creating new **short-lived** pods all the time.

Since [CloudWatch Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/) indicates that we pay 0.30$ per custom metric/month, does that means that I will get billed ~1000x0.30 = 300$? The pricing page also indicates that **All custom metrics charges are prorated by the hour and metered only when you send metrics to CloudWatch**. Since almost all the pods are short-lived (less than an hour), does that mean that I will get billed only ~1000x(0.30/(30days * 24hours)) =
~1000*(0.30/720) = 0.41$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Example 8 - Container Insights for Amazon EKS and Kubernetes (k8s) on the (CloudWatch Pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/) up to 9 metrics will be sent per pod. In there is even clear that the metrics cost is prorated on hourly basis.

I guess the best way to think about is asking yourself how many average running container you'll have during the 30 day period and use that to calculate the cost

```
(n_average_running_pods x 9 x 0.30$USD)
```

Comment: Also see this other answer and the first comment for clarification on the pricing model https://stackoverflow.com/a/55481797/10504841. AWS's docs is quite lacking in this regard